# Best approach for building a chat application ios 6

Tags: ios, web-services, chat, social-networking

we need to create a chat application with a deployment target of iOS 6.
I have the following doubts regarding this,

1.Does apple provide any  SDKs for such application.?
2.Is the chat messages pulled from server at real time using repeating pull requests using a timer?? If so , will that effect memory efficiency and app performance??
3.Do we have to maintain a local cache of each message exchanged??
4.From recent research i learned about C2Call framework. Is this a good option to build a chat application.??

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered completely / objectively. I suggest to start researching on your own and/or get your project going and then post the specific programming problems encountered on your way to the goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can advice to use [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) for iOS. It is open source project that implements XMPP protocol.
As it based on XML format it's easy to extend functionally by adding custom tags for storing any addition data you need.
XMPP protocol has implementations for most of platforms (client- and server-side).
For server side you could use [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/).

Answering on your questions:

1. No, Apple doesn't provide specialised solutions for chat apps.
2. XMPPFramework based on sockets (similar to push notifications mechanism).
3. XMPPFramework provides mechanism for storing chat history in local database (based on CoreData). Also you could load history from server.

Comment: Hi Visput.. thanks for the answer..currently running research on XMPPFramework